# Angular: template reference variable with directives

Tags: angular

I read in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable) that we can use a `template reference variable` on a `custom component` and we can get access to the public methods and properties of this component.

I tried the same on an element with a `directive` and it does not work.

```
<table #myTable my-directive>
    <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--test value is a prop of my directive -->
        <td>Some text: {{ myTable.testValue }}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to use a `template reference variable` with a directive to get access to this directive's properties?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use exportAs property of Directive metadata declartion

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]',
  exportAs: "myDirective"
})
export class MyDirective {
  name: string = "Hello World";
  constructor() { }
}
```

Then in your html you should access as follows

```
<div my-directive #t=myDirective>
  {{ t.name }}
</div>
```